# Python unittest AssertionError: unicode string is not unicode string

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, selenium

I have a web server that returns HTML containing the following:

```
<div class="well">
    <blockquote>
        <h2>Blueberry Pancakes Are Bomb</h2>
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

I wrote a contrived functional test like so:

```
def test_page_has_blueberry_in_blockquote(self):
    # User goes to inspire_my_palate page
    self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000/inspire_my_palate')

    # He sees a blockquote with a header containing 'Blueberry ...'
    food_text = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="well"]/blockquote/h2').text
    self.assertIs(food_text, u'Blueberry Pancakes Are Bomb')
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

```
(foodie_env)fatman:foodie$ python functional_tests.py
.F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_page_has_blueberry_in_blockquote (__main__.NewVisitorNavbar)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "functional_tests.py", line 179, in test_page_has_blueberry_in_blockquote
    self.assertIs(food_text, u'Blueberry Pancakes Are Bomb')
AssertionError: u'Blueberry Pancakes Are Bomb' is not u'Blueberry Pancakes Are Bomb'

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 6.656s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I've also tried:

```
self.assertIs(food_text, 'Blueberry Pancakes Are Bomb')
```

Casting the string as unicode or not doesn't appear to change anything. I still get the same assertion error.

Update: I get a passing test if I change the assertion test to:

```
self.assertEquals(food_text, u'Blueberry Pancakes Are Bomb')
```

However, I'd still still like to know why the `assertIs()` test fails. I'm guessing this is due to how the strings are represented in memory. Intuitively, the assertIs() version should pass since I'm comparing two string types.

The assertion error is not very intuitive and is confusing. What could be causing this weird assertion error?

Comment: Do you need to force the second argument to unicode?

Comment: @dursk Not really, the issue persists. I've tried both with the same results.

Comment: Why do you use `assertIs` and not `assertEqual`?

Comment: I don't think unicode strings are guaranteed to be hashed for uniqueness, so you should probably compare using `==` rather than `is`.  Basically you have two separate copes of the same unicode string, and although they are equal, they refer to separate copies of the same text.

Comment: @alecxe Good point, that was an artefact as I refactored my code. Using `assertEquals()` works. However, theoretically should `assertIs()` have also worked since we're comparing two types (string)? Is `assertIs()` perhaps comparing more than simply the type?

Comment: @TomKarzes Interesting point. I tried to verify that by looking at `unittest` module's source: https://pythonhosted.org/gchecky/unittest-pysrc.html. However, I couldn't find any reference to the `assertIs()` method. Do you happen to know where I could find that?

Comment: Take a look at [unittest doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html) and search for `assertIs`.  Basically it checks if `a is b`, when in fact you want `assertEqual`, which checks if `a == b`.

Comment: @TomKarzes Perfect! So assertIs() is comparing objects rather than types. I'd be more than happy to accept if you propose an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the `assertIs` check with:

```
self.assertEqual(food_text, u'Blueberry Pancakes Are Bomb')
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand more on @TomKarzes's answer, `assertIs()` is evaluating two objects. In the following code, the two strings are represented as two different objects in memory:

```
self.assertEqual(food_text, u'Blueberry Pancakes Are Bomb')
```

Therefore, this assertion will fail, since these two objects do not evaluate to the same thing.

On the other hand, `assertEquals()` is comparing the two strings for likeness, therefore this assertion passes.